# Installing an R package from the source files

Tags: r, package

I am trying to install the [r package "segue" from the source](http://code.google.com/p/segue/source/checkout).  Unfortunately, there's no tarball provided at this time, and I don't know how to compile and install a package from the binary files.  I'm on a mac, if that helps.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the author of Segue, I threw you a bone and [rolled the tar ball](http://code.google.com/p/segue/downloads/list) for you :)

What you see on the Google Code page is not the binary files, they are the source files. Now me doing it for you is not that helpful for helping you understand packages. So if you wanted to build this yourself, here's how you would do it:

1. clone the source tree so you have a local copy on your machine. Make sure you have Mercurial installed and then type `hg clone https://segue.googlecode.com/hg/ segue` to clone the code to your machine.
2. build the package, test it, and install with the following three commands:

   `R CMD build segue/`

   `R CMD check segue_0.02.tar.gz`

   `R CMD INSTALL segue_0.02.tar.gz`

I've never actually used a Mac so I ***think*** these commands are right. I know they work on Linux. So let me know if I need to alter these instructions for Mac. You're helping me write documentation!

Comment: Or within R do: `install.packages("segue_0.02.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")`

Comment: @aL3xa: Is there a way to build from source from within R? Or do I have to build from the source from the command line, and then I can install the tarball from R?